# Getting specified value from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of array

```
$data["products"] =
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productId] => 1
            [productName] => Automatishen Here
            [productDescription] => Before you go banging your head on a wall, have you checked to make sure that this extra is actually installed on your site?
            [productPicture] => 
            [productSubText] => sub-text
            [productTaxonomie] => 1
            [productDateTime] => 2016-12-23 06:49:42
            [isbnNumber] => 1234
            [productIsbn] => 1
            [taxonomieName] => Proba
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productId] => 2
            [productName] => Automatishen Here
            [productDescription] => Before you go banging your head on a wall, have you checked to make sure that this extra is actually installed on your site?
            [productPicture] => 
            [productSubText] => sub-text
            [productTaxonomie] => 1
            [productDateTime] => 2016-12-23 06:49:42
            [isbnNumber] => 456
            [productIsbn] => 3
            [taxonomieName] => Proba
        )

);
```

In all values `[taxonomieName]` is the same, I don't want to foreach that array because it is overload.  I only need one `[taxonomieName]` from that array like I can get

**$name = [taxonomieName];**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the're all the same, you can just grab the first one, right?

`$data['products'][0]['taxonomieName']`